# matplotlib: Error in sys.exitfunc

Tags: python, matplotlib

I keep getting `error in sys.exitfunc` when working with matplotlib. For example, the following code throw it for matplotlib 1.3.0 / Python 2.7.3 / Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, show
from numpy.random import random
fh = figure(figsize = (15, 10, ))
ax = fh.add_axes((.1, .1, .8, .8, ))
ax.scatter(random((100, )), random((100, )))
fh.show()
```

This yields

```
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/_pylab_helpers.py", line 86, in destroy_all
    manager.destroy()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3.py", line 427, in destroy
    self.canvas.destroy()
AttributeError: FigureManagerGTK3Agg instance has no attribute 'canvas'
Error in sys.exitfunc:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/_pylab_helpers.py", line 86, in destroy_all
    manager.destroy()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3.py", line 427, in destroy
    self.canvas.destroy()
AttributeError: FigureManagerGTK3Agg instance has no attribute 'canvas'
```

This happens any time the program terminates without `show()`, including when an unrelated error is raised.

If I use `show()` instead of `fh.show()`, I don't get this error. I could just do that, but this error pops up in a lot of places and I prefer to just solve it (and I want to be able to exit without showing a figure).

I tried other backends which either are unavailable, don't have show or give the same error (this is GKT3Agg).

Comment: I dunno what your problem is, but if you just want a simple scatter plot, take a look at this [code](https://dpaste.de/fv3A).

Comment: Thank you Games Brainiac, the problem is that if I use that example but for any reason close the program without using `plt.show()`, I get an error.

Comment: The problem is that, the `plt.show()` function _does_ work, but it ends abruptly and without an error.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error. Using
      matplotlib.pyplot.close()
at the end of my program fixed it. Perhaps this works for you?

Comment: It doesn't quite work ('no canvas'). As I understand, the canvas isn't created until the figure is drawn, so I can't close them. Creating the canvas manually just moves the error. It might work for other back-ends though, but GTK3Agg seems unable to exit cleanly without showing figures...

Comment: Worked for me with `FigureManagerGTK3Agg`

Answer (score 1):

```
plt.plot(return_array, risk_array)
plt.title('Pareto Front for '+ r'$\lambda \in$ [0.0, 1.0]')
plt.xlabel('Return')
plt.ylabel('Risk')
plt.axis([0.02, 0.05, 0.01, 0.016])
```

only using above code gives error but adding

```
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

in the end works for me

Comment: That is right, but it is not always desirable to show all figures

Answer (score 0):

dowload matplotlib-1.3.1.tar.gz  from http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.3.1/

```
cd matplotlib-1.3.1

sudo python setup.py install
```

before that install following

```
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev

sudo apt-get install python-dev

sudo apt-get install libevent-dev

sudo apt-get install libpng-dev
```

Comment: Could someone else with this problem verify this solution? My new computer doesn't have the problem anymore so I can't check.

Comment: @Mark, I have the same problem with Ubuntu 12.04 - this does not fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and the solution of ShikharDua solved the problem for me. My system: ubuntu 13.10 64 bit.

I wanted to run an example code which didn't call the `plt.show()` function at the end resulting in:
`AttributeError: FigureManagerGTK3Agg instance has no attribute 'canvas'`

Interestingly, the same code, without the `plt.show()`, worked in ipython if `pylab` is invoked before.

edit: Ok, i just read, that you mentioned this in your question already. So, this not really a solution for you. However, it is a solution for beginners who were wondering why some example codes don't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is my horrible hack to get around it:

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 # your use of matplotlib here where you don't use the plot.show() function

 try:
   plt.close()
 except AttributeError, e:
   pass
```